# Downloading filtered and sorted data from a reactable in a Shiny app

Tags: r, shiny, reactable

I'm developing a Shiny app that utilizes the reactable package for tabular data representation. Users can filter and sort columns in the table. I'd like to provide a download button that allows users to download the table data considering the filtering and sorting they may have done.

I am familiar with the rhandsontable package which provides the hot_to_r() function to achieve similar functionality. I'm looking for a parallel solution for reactable.

Below is a basic Shiny app that attempts to provide the desired functionality:

```
library(shiny)
library(reactable)

ui <- fluidPage(
  downloadButton("downloadData", "Download Data"),
  reactableOutput("my_table")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  output$my_table <- renderReactable({
    reactable(head(mtcars), filterable = TRUE)
  })
  
  # Placeholder for downloadHandler
  output$downloadData <- downloadHandler(
    filename = function() {
      paste("data.csv")
    },
    content = function(file) {
      # Attempt to capture and save the current state of the table
      fwrite(as.data.table(head(mtcars)), file)
    },
    contentType = 'text/csv'
  )
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

For instance, I filtered for a `speed` of 10 and sorted the data by the `dist` column. How can I download the data displayed in the picture below?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT**

Building on the approach by [Victor Perrier](https://github.com/glin/reactable/issues/265#issuecomment-1230034720) we could get the sorted and filtered data via `Reactable.getState('my_table').sortedData` and pass it to shiny via `Shiny.setInputValue`. Additionally I had to add an input handler to convert the `list` into a `data.frame`:

```
library(shiny)
library(reactable)

convertToDataFrame <- function(x, session, inputname) {
  do.call("rbind.data.frame", x)
}

registerInputHandler("to_csv", convertToDataFrame, force = TRUE)

ui <- fluidPage(
  downloadButton(
    "downloadData", "Download",
    onClick = "Shiny.setInputValue('table_state:to_csv', Reactable.getState('my_table').sortedData)"
  ),
  reactableOutput("my_table"),
  tableOutput("test")
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$my_table <- renderReactable({
    reactable(head(mtcars), filterable = TRUE)
  })
  output$test <- renderTable({
    input$table_state
  })
  output$downloadData <- downloadHandler(
    filename = function() {
      paste("data-", Sys.Date(), ".csv", sep = "")
    },
    content = function(file) {
      data <- input$table_state
      write.csv(data, file)
    }
  )
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]

**Original Post**

Following the example in the [docs](https://glin.github.io/reactable/articles/javascript-api.html#introduction) you can download your filtered and sorted data table by using the reactable download handler for the `onclick=` event.

```
library(shiny)
library(reactable)

ui <- fluidPage(
  downloadButton("foo",
    "Download Data",
    onclick = "Reactable.downloadDataCSV('my_table', 'data.csv')"
  ),
  reactableOutput("my_table")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$my_table <- renderReactable({
    reactable(head(mtcars), filterable = TRUE)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

This is the result when filtering for `cyl=6` and sorting by `mpg`:

[image]

Comment: Nice! The filtering does work, but the column sorting is not being saved. Also, when clicking the download button, there are two files that are being downloaded: data.csv and download.htm

Comment: Yup. You are right. The sorting does not work. Will have a look. But I can't reproduce the issue with the two files. On my machine only a data.csv gets downloaded.

Comment: Thanks! The two files issue is not important, but the sorting is.

Comment: According to [docs](https://glin.github.io/reactable/articles/javascript-api.html#reactable-downloaddatacsv), "the downloaded data will include any filters that have been applied, and exclude any sorting or grouping. Hidden columns will also be included, but this may be customizable in the future."  
Issue [#265](https://github.com/glin/reactable/issues/265) might be useful to go through...

Comment: Hi Mat. Sorry for the late response. Just had a look at the docs myself before I saw the comment by Radovan. And unfortunately he's right. The downloadDataCSV method will only keep the filters. But the issue he referenced offers may offer possible option to achieve your desired result.

Comment: @stefan in the last comment of the GitHub they mention that the table sorting state can now be gathered in the development version of reactable. Any chance you could please update your response based on the dev version of reactable so that the sorting works as well? Many thanks!

Comment: Hi Mat. See my edit for an approach building on the code in the Github issue.